# Relation between Automorphism group of a graph and its subgraph

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph on $r$ vertices $\{1,2,\ldots,r\}$. Further denote $H$ to be the sub-graph of $G$ induced by the vertices $\{1,2,\ldots,(r-1)\}$. Denote $Aut(G)$ and $Aut(H)$ to be the automorphism group of graphs $G$ and $H$ respectively. Is it true that
$$
|Aut(G)| \le r |Aut(H)|,
$$
or even
$$
|Aut(G)| \le C r |Aut(H)|,
$$
for some universal constant $C$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your first question is yes, this follows from the orbit-stabiliser theorem.
If H is the subgraph obtained by removing the vertex $v$, then $Aut(H)$ will contain a copy of the vertex-stabiliser $Aut(G)_v$ (although it may be bigger). By the orbit-stabiliser theorem, $|Aut(G):Aut(G)_v|\leq r$ and the result follows.

Comment: Hi Verret, thanks a lot. Can you suggest a good read/reference on these, i.e. on relation between automorphism group of a graph and its vertex deleted sub-graphs.

Answer (score 2):

Take $X$ to be a Paley graph on $q$ vertices. Then $|\mathrm{Aut}(X)\ge q(q-1)/4$. But $X$ contains, as induced subgraphs, all finite graphs on
something like $\log(q)$ vertices (Bollobas and Thomason); in particular it has asymmetric subgraphs of this order.

For another family of examples take a group $G$ which admits a Cayley graph $X$ such that $\mathrm{Aut}(X)\cong G$. (A so-called graphical representation of $G$, aka GRR.) Then the subgraph of $X$ we get by deleting a vertex is asymmetric. Finite groups of order greater than 32 that are not abelian with exponent greater than two, or generalized dicyclic, always have a GRR.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your answer. I have three questions:

(i) In the Paley graph example, the asymmetric subgraph that one gets is not a vertex deleted subgraph of the original Paley graph, so I am not sure how that applies here.

(ii) In the second example the size of the vertex set of the Cayley graph $X$ is $|G|$. Hence, we have $|Aut(X)|=|G|=r$ in this case, because we are looking for a graph on $r$ vertices. So the fact that $|Aut(X\setminus\{v\})|=1$ does not violate the claim in the question.

Comment: (iii) I am interested in Paley graph in a different context. Can you provide the ref. for Bollobas and Thompson. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @anirban basak: Sorry for missing the vertex-de;eted requirement. The Bollabas-Thomason result is in European J. Combinatorics 2 (1981).